# classifier / recommender for images - unsupervised machine learning / neural networks / logistic

Tags: node.js, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, unsupervised-learning

So, given a set of tens to hundreds of images, whom I don't have control over, but I know they are classified as 1/0, which technique, is best suited for recommending / classifying images?

it needs to be a robust , scaled system. I don't know which features will play role , that's why it's `unsupervised learning`.

It needs to be robust and scalable, because there is 10th / 100th / 1000th of images per user.

I would like to use  `node.js` for the process, so if you've done something similar and have an idea in mind, please help.

If you need more info, please let me know. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you ever come up with a technique for this question? Many thanks.